# Deleting filler words with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, text

I have a collection of text and I am trying to find and replace all 'filler words' with blank spaces: Filler words in this instance refers to things such as "hmm", "uh", "ha" that occur in ordinary speech.

I'm using regular expressions, and can generally remove what I need to with the code I currently have aside from some exceptions

Consider the below sentences:

```
fw_end = 'Foo bar Foo bar hm' # filler at end of sentence
fw_start = 'hmmm foo bar foo bar' # filler at start of sentence
fw_startCap = 'Hmm foo bar foo bar' # (capitalized) filler at start of sentence
fw_mid = 'foo bar hmmmmm foo bar' # filler in middle of sentences
```

Using the below I can remove the 'hmm' of varying lengths from all cases except where the H is capitalized (fw_startCap):

```
def applyRegExp(textFiller):
    textClean = re.sub('^(?!mom|am|ham)[u*|h*|m*|o*|a*]+[m*|h*|u*|a*]+\s', ' ', textFiller) # at the start of a string
    textClean = re.sub('\s(?!mom|am|ham)[u*|h*|m*|o*|a*]+[m*|h*|u*|a*]+\s', ' ', textClean) # within a string
    textClean = re.sub('\s(?!mom|am|ham)[u*|h*|m*|o*|a*]+[m*|h*|u*|a*]$', ' ', textClean) # end of a string
    textClean = re.sub('^(?!mom|am|ham)[u*|h*|m*|o*|a*]+[m*|h*|u*|a*]$', ' ', textClean) # if entire turn string

    return textClean
```

**Note:** 'mom', 'am', and 'ham' are non-filler words that would also get caught up in this rule

So, my next attempt was to include uppercase equivalents in the first part of the equation after the negative lookahead:

```
def applyRegExp_WITHCAP(textFiller):
    textClean = re.sub('^(?!mom|am|ham)[U*|H*|M*|O*|A*]|[u*|h*|m*|o*|a*]+[m*|h*|u*|a*]+\s', ' ', textFiller) # at the start of a string
    textClean = re.sub('\s(?!mom|am|ham)[U*|H*|M*|O*|A*]|[u*|h*|m*|o*|a*]+[m*|h*|u*|a*]+\s', ' ', textClean) # within a string
    textClean = re.sub('\s(?!mom|am|ham)[U*|H*|M*|O*|A*]|[u*|h*|m*|o*|a*]+[m*|h*|u*|a*]$', ' ', textClean) # end of a string
    textClean = re.sub('^(?!mom|am|ham)[U*|H*|M*|O*|A*]|[u*|h*|m*|o*|a*]+[m*|h*|u*|a*]$', ' ', textClean) # if entire turn string

    return textClean
```

This achieves what I needed, however has introduced undesired filtering. For instance, on the below sentence I am having problems with the word "You":

```
you_sent = 'You are causing my regex to fail' # problem sentence
```

Running the `applyRegExp_WITHCAP` code strips the 'ou' portion of 'You', and I cannot work out why. My interpretation of what I *thought* my code was doing was akin to: "look at the start/middle/end of the string for anything that is not "mom", "am" or "ham", then look for one of the following in capital/lowercase: Uu, Hh, Mm, Oo, Aa - followed by one or more lowercase m, h, u or a".

In short, I cannot work out why 'You' would be filtered, given that I have not specified a capital 'Y'.

**Note:** I recognize that I could possibly lowercase everything, however for later purposes that will not be possible.

**Edit:** Following comments I can provide a little more detail regarding what I am trying to achieve. I have a large amount of conversational text transcribed by different people, using varying standards of transcription. Without a defined dictionary of 'filler words' at the offset, there is no control over (1) the type of filler words to be used, and (2) their correct spelling. For instance, a sound of agreement may appear in the corpus as "mm", "mmm", "hm", "hmm", "hmmm", "mm-hmm" and so on. I am looking for a relatively simple way to capture the majority of these and remove them from the corpus.

Comment: Did you mean to use an alternation here? `(?:U*|H*|M*|O*|A)` instead of a character class `[U*|H*|M*|O*|A*]`

Comment: Possibly - I'm still getting to grips with regex so the terminology is a little lost on me. But in essence, i think what I want is an alternation yes. For that particular part I am essentially saying "please find an instance of U, H, M, O, A in capitalized form or lowercase form."

Comment: As @Thefourthbird mentioned, you need to change your set to an alternation (right now you're matching any character in `U*|HMOA` one or more times). Also, write your rules in your question (in plaintext) so that we can fix the regex.

Comment: Thanks - I think I understand. For my own future reference (as per your comment re writing in plain text), is that not what I'd done at the end, by stating what i wanted the  code to do? Forgive the ignorance, I just want to make sure I've understood your comment.

Comment: @DC_Liv yes I suppose so, but to clarify, you're looking to match any of `uhmoa` (case-insensitive - once), followed by any of `mhua` (lowercase only - one or more)?

Comment: @ctwheels great, that makes perfect sense - and yes that is exactly what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Regex is Okay at this sort of task, but just splitting on whitespace, running the list of words through a filter and checking against a set of no-no words seems fine (although I guess your intent is to match `hm`, `hmmmmmm`, `hmmmmmmmm`?). In any event, whitelisting `"mom"`, `"am"`, `"ham"` seems like you're in for a tough time with the regex approach too, pretty easy to miss an edge case or a hundred. I'd recommend zooming out and explaining a bit more thoroughly what the end goal is, exactly, then letting the answerers pick the best tool for the job.

Comment: For example, if you have a whitelisted dictionary of valid words that doesn't include `"ha"`, `"hmm"`, `"hmmmmm"` and so forth, then split on whitespace and perform lookups on the dict for each word. This also eliminates non-words like `"asdasdad"`. This might be less futile than trying to blacklist everything you don't want, but it's use-case dependent.

Comment: @DC_Liv does [this](https://regex101.com/r/z5hA2t/1) work for you: `( )*\b(?!h?am)[uhmoaUHMOA][mhua]+\b(?!\1\b) *`?

Comment: A heads up here, the assertion in this sequence will always be true `(?! mom | am | ham ) [U*|H*|M*|O*|A*]` even if it was `(?!mom|am|ham)[UHMOA]+` since it requires an upper case start letter and that does not exist in the assertion.

Comment: @ctwheels - that does seem to have done the trick. I think I'm following what it's doing sufficiently. more importantly its having the desired effect on my text. Thanks.

Comment: @DC_Liv you're welcome, as @x15 mentioned though, change my negative lookahead from `(?!h?am)` to `(?!Ham|Am)`